# Removing duplicate values within rows using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table

How can I remove duplicate values within a text field using ArcPy?

The following example shows a list of numbers for each row in a featureclass, some with duplicate numbers.

I am aware of UpdateCursors (code snippet below), however, I am unsure how to remove the duplicate numbers that happen to be in string format.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ("field")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following using an [Update Cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm). This assumes 1) your input and output fields are text fields and 2) you have created a new field `new_field` in which you will write your results.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\featureclass'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ("dup_field", "new_field")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: # Iterate through each row
        if row[0] is not None: # Only perform actions if there is not a None value in row
            a = sorted(set(int(x) for x in row[0].split(','))) # Manipulate text field, convert to integer so that 
            b = str(a).strip('[').strip(']')
            row[1] = b # Write the results 
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

---

The following line converts the text to a list of integer values, which we can then use `set()` to isolate unique values. `sorted()` obviously sorts the values

```
a = sorted(set(int(x) for x in row[0].split(',')))
```

This line cleans up the results of `a` by convert to text and removing the brackets so we can write the string back to the attribute table

```
b = str(a).strip('[').strip(']')
```

---

[image]

Comment: If the original order is important it is also possible to use collections.OrderedDict: `",".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(row[0].split(',')))`